# LINQ and DB can not retrieve correct data back

Tags: c#, linq

```
var date = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-3);

var query = from p in _context.Set<works>()
            join r in _context.Set<customers>() on p.CustomerId equals r.Id
            where r.Id == customerId
               && p.IsApproved == true
               && p.EmployerId == employerId
               && p.WorkStartOn <= date
               && p.WorkEndOn >= DateTime.Today
            orderby p.Name
            select p;
```

Where `date` is `12.10.2015`

DB:

[image]

But we can not get any data back. If I remove date check then I get data back. Why? Dates are valid!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  p.WorkStartOn      == 05/Nov/2015
  (Today - 3 months) == 12/Oct/2015
```

p.WorkStartOn is greater than (Today - 3 months), so that record will not be returned.

Comment: you are right, how can I missed that. But it is actually valid date because everything what is from 3 months till today is valid

Comment: So perhaps your comparisons should be the other way around:  p.WorkStartOn >= date && p.WorkEndOn <= DateTime.Today